# How to pass string variables in sqlite query in android project?

Tags: android, sqlite

`Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM Birds WHERE Size LIKE "+"'"+size+"'"+" AND Color1 LIKE "+"'"+color1+"'"+" AND Color2 LIKE "+"'"+color2+"'"+" AND Habitat LIKE "+"'"+habitat+"'"+";",null);`

`Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM Birds WHERE Size LIKE 'Duck%' AND  Color1 LIKE 'Orange%'  AND  Color2 LIKE 'White%' AND   Habitat LIKE 'Wetland%';",null);`

`Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery(sql,null);
resultset.moveToFirst();
name=resultset.getString(0);`

The first statement Cursor resultset contains string variable names but it shows error-
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundException:Index 0 requested,with size of 0.

The second statement Cursor resultset gets executed Duck is value under Size column in database,
Orange is value under Color1 column in database
and White is value under Color2 column in database

So I dont know to improve the first sqlite query so it actually works
Because the string variables size,color1 and color2 are getting updated with actual values.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

```
Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM Birds WHERE Size LIKE ? AND Color1 LIKE ? AND Color2 LIKE ? AND Habitat LIKE ?",null);
String[] arguments= new String[]{"Duck%", "Orange%", "White%", "Wetland%"};
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, arguments);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The first one is valid but selects no rows, the **out of bounds issue** is because the Cursor is empty and you have the following:-

```
Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery(sql,null); // OK
resultset.moveToFirst(); // OK BUT WILL ALLOW EMPTY CURSOR
name=resultset.getString(0); // OUT OF BOUNDS IF EMPTY CURSOR
```

Rather you should use something like :-

```
Cursor resultset=mydb.rawQuery(sql,null);
if (resultset.moveToFirst()) {
    name=resultset.getString(0);
}
```

That is, the `moveToFirst` method returns a boolean indicating whether or not the **move** could be accomplished and this should be checked to see if the move was in fact accomplished and that there is in fact a row to be processed.

*Note! you should probably handle the situation when no rows are returned.*